# What information is available on EPM to APM comparisons?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've been looking for information on EPM it relates to APM statistically (fractions/percentages/ratios) of APM. Information desired would include:

- **EPM and APM combined, across leagues**. This could show minimal requirements for EPM, as well as the typical level of APM required for a given EPM within a league.
- **EPM and APM combined of some professional players**. This would allow a more objective comparison between two professional players, as well as between professional players and non-professional players.
- **EPM and APM combined, across a wide APM band**. This would potentially answer such questions as: "How does EPM as a percentage of APM vary as APM increases?"

I am NOT looking for:

- [What is the difference between EPM and APM?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63467/what-is-the-difference-between-epm-and-apm)
- The value or usefulness of EPM or APM as a measurement.

Comment: I realise that this question could be broken up into multiple questions, but I expect there to be such sparse information on the matter that likely all the available information will function as a single answer.

Comment: Ok, I have finished a script that can extract the APM and EPM from a given replay (not player specific). If you provide me a few thousand replays for every league I can extract you the raw data (in Excel).

Comment: Old post I know - but the data required for this question is just plain insane, to meet the needs for a propper result. And I can asure, that you can have an APM on 400 in bronze and 90 in Diamond, and still performe to the league your in.

Comment: @AtlasEU, we don't shy away from insanely detailed questions and answers, that's actually kind of our forte :)

Comment: @agent86 Touché :) Sure thing, but IMO its an insane amount of data for a very little gain.